# Fastest way to send data from C# to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, send, transfer

I have two separate apps. One of them is a UI web application written with pure JS, the other one is console application written by C#.

Currently I'm calculating some variables (which can not done in JS because of browser limitations) with C# console app, then it's writing results to a txt file.

Then I read the file with JS application to bring results to UI. But the variable often changes in milliseconds and writing results to disk and retrieving it again is pretty slow.

What can I do? Any suggestions?

Comment: Websockets should do

Comment: What browser limitations? This design is unconventional to say the least!

Comment: Use signalr connection. Writing to a text file and reading from js seems like a bad design.

Comment: write your console app as a web api app and use signalR to send the data as it changes.  For best peformance, send as diffs to current data

Comment: Ya make the c# app an api and you can simply call it to do what you need

Comment: Can JS in a browser really read a file from the local disk repeatedly without the user having to choose it every time?

Comment: firstly see sharper I collect data from user's PC input etc. even while he/she is using other softwares(outside browser), and caius yes i start a HTTP server and request file that exists in the same folder i make a xmlhttprequest without letting user choose file everytime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console application is effectively a *server*. Communicating between a web app and a server by means of a local text file is, well, unconventional! If this is not just for your own use on the one machine, it will be very difficult to deploy for another user. Write a small server application and communicate with it the usual way, i.e, by posting the data to the server's IP address and receiving the server's response. You can remove any connection latency (after the initial connection) by communicating over websocket.

Comment: No - you can open the connection and keep it open, and henceforth communicate without the connection latency. I edited to clarify that.

Comment: thanks for reply, should i create a new aspx project to apply this? or is it not necessary?

Comment: A Web API project probably. There are a lot of ways to go - see Caius Jard’s answer below. I would not go down the websockets or signalR path until you are sure that a simple http request is not actually fast enough. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out WebSockets seem to be a great choice for this task.

Mozilla has a mini tutorial that seems perfect for this task: [Writing a WebSocket server in C#](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_server).

RE: Comment:

Good point! There is also a MSFT guide for SignalR: [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Lot more hard work than SignalR, which abstracts away a lot of this low level stuff

Answer (score 0):

It's open to some debate what you mean by "fastest" - fastest for you to write or fastest in terms of performance of the app..

It's relatively simple to turn your C# code into an API - visual studio has templates for API type projects; your logic will then get a url and can be triggered simply by visiting it in any browser or having JavaScript do a fetch of the url. The url itself can be used to pass variable data, C# knows how to parse it and present it in code so a method like (attributes etc removed for clarity)

```
public class CalcController:ApiController{
  public int Add(int a, int b){
    return a+ b;
  }
}
```

Can be triggered by visiting a url of `http://host/api/add/1/2 and you get JSON back, which JS understands out of the box. If your web app serves your js up the js can automatically talk to the web app without any CORS etc because it was served by the same server

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0 for a full tutorial (it's pretty involved, uses databases and everything - you can boil it down a lot simpler, probably even just making a web app project from a SPA template in vs will create  everything you need to have front end JS and back end C#

---

Another option to look at is Blazor; you can dump the JS entirely and put c# in the browser (or leave c# on the server and let Blazor handle transiting the UI changes between client and server) if you want, or you can interoperate with JS

---

Finally it's been commented about SignalR - a tech from MS that builds on top of websockets and handles the connectivity management, and finding and calling code on either end. It helps create event driven apps where the events happen at either end (like a chat app; one person speaks, it causes JS in their browser to call a method on the server and transits what they types to the server, then the server pushes that message out to a group of other connected clients). You set up events in your JS like "onChatReceived" so when the server pushes data, you respond to it. SignalR deals firewalls automatically; it either uses websockets (long lived bidirectional data flow), long polling (make a request and the server doesn't answer until a message it available to send) or repeated polling (any update? any update? any update?) automatically, so it can make your app very portable, especially if one day you want to host your calculations on a server you control, to protect you're intellectual property

Full MS tutorial on SignalR here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio - you're essentially setting up a group of eventing mechanisms; your JS can trigger your server to do something and later your server can trigger your JS to do something.

This is slightly different to your JS requesting your server do something and waiting for the response - that model might work fine and be simpler for you to implement as its most close to what you already have, you're just swapping out the file reading for a network call, which JS is allowed to do autonomously